# Wampserver err_connection_refused

Tags: apache, wampserver

I want to hosting my website. Here is my steps,

1. installed wampserver 3.0.6 64 bit (win7)
2. ipconfig own ip 192.168.1.2
3. [open port [img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OujE9.jpg)
4. Wampserver tested 5050 port
5. whatismyip , restart wampserver, put online,firewall close,antivirus close with all procecs
6. [image: Here is my httpd.conf]
7. > 88.227.xxx.yyy:5050/

   **Forbidden
   You don't have permission to access / on this server.**
8. if i change these in httpd-vhosts.conf:

ServerName localhost => ServerName 192.168.1.2

Require local => Require all granted

> 88.227.xxx.yyy:5050/

i dont get error but i cant acces from public another internet connection (err_connection_refused)

Comment: if the connection is refused is has nothing to do with Apache as you can verify it runs fine. The issue is with your router port forwarding. Some ISPs block certain ports and you need to disable the firewall at their level. Check with them first.

Comment: Can you show your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file please

Comment: I would also suggest you upgrade to WAMPServer 3.0.9. [Upgrade install availble here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) This will just upgrade the WAMPServer code, and not change anything to do with Apache/MySQL/PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly <VirtualHost *:5050> 
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot d:/wamp64/www
 <Directory  "d:/wamp64/www/">
  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: @Capsule i tested 5050 with http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ says its closed but i installed port forwarding wizard and configure for listen 5050 port says open. so my port is open but apache dosent listen i think.

Comment: This problem solved by itself